# Import a Git repo from a local server to DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops

How can I import a Git repo from a local server to DevOps? I am not talking about a depo already hosted on GitHub, but a bare repo that is just living on a local server.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*? You should be able to just add a new remote and push the repo. Did that not work?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. All your feedback helped me to solve my problem.

I was focused on import, only import. And it seems like it's not possible to directly import from a local repo.

The solution was to create an empty repo in DevOps, add it as remote to my local repo (git remote add), and push to this remote (git push -u). As simple as this, and probably obvious for most people but it wasn't for me!

Answer (score -1):

There is only two way:

**One:**

You need to host the repo to a remote server (github etc.) which is accessible by both local machine and DevOps machine.

**Two:**

You most likely need to clone the local git project to DevOps machine. In this way you can use `scp` tools to copy the repo to other machine. For example. i have repo in user's home directory `/home/local_machine/git_project`.

copy git repo using remote machine:

```
scp -r <username>@<local_machine_ip>:/home/local_machine/git_project /home/devops_machine/
```

In this way you will be able to clone or copy local git repository without using 3rd party hosting sites.

Comment: This answer is entirely incorrect.